# textbook of measure theory abstracted as functional analysis

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions

### Background

I have studied intro functional analysis, probability theory based on measures, and some elementary connection between them e.g. that weak conversion of random variables correspond to weak* convergence, and Helly's thm is an instance of a property of weak* compact sets.

So now I am assuming that I can get a concise understanding of theories of probability and random processes based on measure theory if tools and notations of functional analysis are utilized.

### Question

My question is, does anybody know a good textbook of
- measure theory
- probability theory based on measure theory
- random process theory
that has explicit formulation as functional analysis?

Comment: I don't think this question is a good fit for MO, but "Integration - A Functional Approach" by Klaus Bichteler is based on functional analysis and "Topological Riesz Spaces and Measure Theory" by David Fremlin is basically an advanced functional analytic treatment of measure theory. If you just want to learn more about connections between functional analysis and probability, you can read "Functional Analysis for Probability and Stochastic Processes" by Adam Bobrowski. And then there are areas like probability theory in Banach spaces that directly combine both areas in terms of their subject.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that the question is off-topic, and for showing the references too. I will look into those books.